# Azure Pipelines or Azure Boards for Microsoft Teams - Commercial Azure DevOps to Govt. Teams

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams, azure-gov

Is there a way to add Azure Pipelines or Boards for Microsoft Teams Govt. subscription to a Commercial Azure DevOps subscription.  All of our development work is in commercial space, but our Teams is part of our Office 365 Government subscription.  I've tried to add the app to Teams, but always get either "Sorry, this didn't work" or "this app doesn't exist or has been blocked by your administrator".  The latter is not true as I checked to make sure 3rd party apps are available.

Both use the same Azure AD.

BTW - webhooks don't work either.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Red

Comment: Checking it internally

Comment: Any headway?  I have tried again, but still the same results.

Comment: This will not work.
As of now this doesn't support.

Comment: Thank you for checking.  I've found a way to use Power Automate to do most of the things that the Slack / DevOps integration does.

Comment: @keltic88  Would you please convert your comment into an answer ? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

We were able to create most of the Slack / Azure DevOps integration functions (build notifications, code push, etc.) by using Microsoft Power Automate flows. If you have a GCC subscription to Office365, check to see if you have Power Automate.

There are connectors in Power Automate to MS Teams and Azure DevOps which give you the triggers and actions that can produce nearly the same types of messages that we see in Slack.  While Adaptive Cards aren't working in GCC yet, you can format the message using HTML and dynamic content:
[Example of using HTML in message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nakyT.png)

The Azure DevOps apps for Teams aren't working in GCC (yet), but with Power Automate you might be able to overcome some of these limitations.